# Sort data into matching column PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort a table into the right section. I have a database with users and they all have a rank assigned to each. In each section there should be a table displaying all the users in that rank. Example:

**Manager**

```
ID | rank    | username | email          | password
---------------------------------------------------
70 | Manager | MyUser   | email@mail.com | pswrd
---------------------------------------------------
70 | Manager | MyUser   | email@mail.com | pswrd
```

**Admin**

```
ID | rank    | username | email           | password
---------------------------------------------------
9  | Admin   | userName | email@email.com | pswrd22
```

I'd like to make it using a while loop. What I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<?php

    $tUsers_Select = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN ranks ON ranks.rankName = users.rank";
    $tRanks_Select = "SELECT * FROM ranks";

    $tUsers_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tUsers_Select);
    $tRanks_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tRanks_Select);

?>

<body>

    <?php

    while ($users_item = mysqli_fetch_array($tUsers_Select_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $ID = $users_item['ID'];
        $rank = $users_item['rank'];
        $username = $users_item['username'];
        $email = $users_item['email'];
        $password = $users_item['password'];
    }

    while ($ranks_item = mysqli_fetch_array($tRanks_Select_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $rankName = $ranks_item['rankName'];
        $value = $ranks_item['value'];

        echo '<h2>'.$rankName.'</h2>';
    }


    ?>



    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>rank</td>
            <td>username</td>
            <td>email</td>
            <td>password</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>
```

If you need any more details, please comment.

Comment: It seems like the easiest solution would just be to make multiple queries, 1 for each rank then putting them into a table is trivial.

Comment: I could do that, but when I add a new rank, I'd have to keep updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better done with prepared statements. But here you go

```
<?php


$tRanks_Select = "SELECT `rankName` FROM `ranks`";
$tRanks_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tRanks_Select);

while ($ranks_item = mysqli_fetch_array($tRanks_Select_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rankName = $ranks_item['rankName'];

    echo '<h2>'. $rankName .'</h2>';


    while ($users_item = mysqli_fetch_array($tUsers_Select_Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $tUsers_Select = "SELECT `ID`, `rank`, `username`, `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = '{$rankName}'";
        $tUsers_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tUsers_Select);

        $ID       = $users_item['ID'];
        $rank     = $users_item['rank'];
        $username = $users_item['username'];
        $email    = $users_item['email'];
        $password = $users_item['password'];

        echo <<<EOD
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>rank</td>
                    <td>username</td>
                    <td>email</td>
                    <td>password</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$ID</td>
                    <td>$rank</td>
                    <td>$username</td>
                    <td>$email</td>
                    <td>$password</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        EOD;
    }
}

?>
```